# How to Deserialize string using Newtonsoft.Json library into custom object using C#

Tags: c#, ajax, json, json.net, deserialization

I have a .NET 3.5 project. In ajax call I create json object like this:

```
var jsonAOData = JSON.stringify(aoData);
...
data: "{jsonAOData : '" + jsonAOData + "'}"
...
```

then I pass it to a code behind WebMethod

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static string jQueryDataTable(string jsonAOData)
{
// Deserialize json into object
var customObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<NameValue>>(jsonAOData);
```

I need to deserialize the object into a CustomParams object.

Here my object:

```
[Serializable]
public class NameValue
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class CustomParams
{
    public string sEcho { get; set; }
    public string iColumns { get; set; }
    public string sColumns { get; set; }
    public string iDisplayStart { get; set; }
    public string iDisplayLength { get; set; }
    public string mDataProp_0 { get; set; }
    public string sSearch_0 { get; set; }
    public string bRegex_0 { get; set; }
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
    public string bSearchable_0 { get; set; }
    public string bSortable_0 { get; set; }
    public string mDataProp_1 { get; set; }
    public string sSearch_1 { get; set; }
    public string bRegex_1 { get; set; }
    public string bSearchable_1 { get; set; }
    public string bSortable_1 { get; set; }
    public string mDataProp_2 { get; set; }
    public string sSearch_2 { get; set; }
    public string bRegex_2 { get; set; }
    public string bSearchable_2 { get; set; }
    public string bSortable_2 { get; set; }
    public string mDataProp_3 { get; set; }
    public string sSearch_3 { get; set; }
    public string bRegex_3 { get; set; }
    public string bSearchable_3 { get; set; }
    public string bSortable_3 { get; set; }
    public string mDataProp_4 { get; set; }
    public string sSearch_4 { get; set; }
    public string bRegex_4 { get; set; }
    public string bSearchable_4 { get; set; }
    public string bSortable_4 { get; set; }
    public string mDataProp_5 { get; set; }
    public string sSearch_5 { get; set; }
    public string bRegex_5 { get; set; }
    public string bSearchable_5 { get; set; }
    public string bSortable_5 { get; set; }
    public string mDataProp_6 { get; set; }
    public string sSearch_6 { get; set; }
    public string bRegex_6 { get; set; }
    public string bSearchable_6 { get; set; }
    public string bSortable_6 { get; set; }
    public string mDataProp_7 { get; set; }
    public string sSearch_7 { get; set; }
    public string bRegex_7 { get; set; }
    public string bSearchable_7 { get; set; }
    public string bSortable_7 { get; set; }
    public string sSearch { get; set; }
    public string bRegex { get; set; }
    public string iSortCol_0 { get; set; }
    public string sSortDir_0 { get; set; }
    public string iSortingCols { get; set; }

}
```

I would gladly provide more information if needed. Thanks.

Update:

I have customObj with all the Names, Values
Screen is attached:

[image]

I need to still transfer all that data into CustomParams.

This is a data from debugger code behind for jsonAOData (just a string) that is passed into

```
string jsonAOData
```

Here a data:

```
[{\"name\":\"sEcho\",\"value\":1},{\"name\":\"iColumns\",\"value\":8},{\"name\":\"sColumns\",\"value\":\",,,,,,,\"},{\"name\":\"iDisplayStart\",\"value\":0},{\"name\":\"iDisplayLength\",\"value\":10},{\"name\":\"mDataProp_0\",\"value\":0},{\"name\":\"sSearch_0\",\"value\":\"\"},{\"name\":\"bRegex_0\",\"value\":false},{\"name\":\"bSearchable_0\",\"value\":true},{\"name\":\"bSortable_0\",\"value\":true},{\"name\":\"mDataProp_1\",\"value\":1},{\"name\":\"sSearch_1\",\"value\":\"\"},{\"name\":\"bRegex_1\",\"value\":false},{\"name\":\"bSearchable_1\",\"value\":true},{\"name\":\"bSortable_1\",\"value\":true},{\"name\":\"mDataProp_2\",\"value\":2},{\"name\":\"sSearch_2\",\"value\":\"\"},{\"name\":\"bRegex_2\",\"value\":false},{\"name\":\"bSearchable_2\",\"value\":true},{\"name\":\"bSortable_2\",\"value\":true},{\"name\":\"mDataProp_3\",\"value\":3},{\"name\":\"sSearch_3\",\"value\":\"\"},{\"name\":\"bRegex_3\",\"value\":false},{\"name\":\"bSearchable_3\",\"value\":true},{\"name\":\"bSortable_3\",\"value\":true},{\"name\":\"mDataProp_4\",\"value\":4},{\"name\":\"sSearch_4\",\"value\":\"\"},{\"name\":\"bRegex_4\",\"value\":false},{\"name\":\"bSearchable_4\",\"value\":true},{\"name\":\"bSortable_4\",\"value\":true},{\"name\":\"mDataProp_5\",\"value\":5},{\"name\":\"sSearch_5\",\"value\":\"\"},{\"name\":\"bRegex_5\",\"value\":false},{\"name\":\"bSearchable_5\",\"value\":true},{\"name\":\"bSortable_5\",\"value\":true},{\"name\":\"mDataProp_6\",\"value\":6},{\"name\":\"sSearch_6\",\"value\":\"\"},{\"name\":\"bRegex_6\",\"value\":false},{\"name\":\"bSearchable_6\",\"value\":true},{\"name\":\"bSortable_6\",\"value\":true},{\"name\":\"mDataProp_7\",\"value\":7},{\"name\":\"sSearch_7\",\"value\":\"\"},{\"name\":\"bRegex_7\",\"value\":false},{\"name\":\"bSearchable_7\",\"value\":true},{\"name\":\"bSortable_7\",\"value\":true},{\"name\":\"sSearch\",\"value\":\"\"},{\"name\":\"bRegex\",\"value\":false},{\"name\":\"iSortCol_0\",\"value\":0},{\"name\":\"sSortDir_0\",\"value\":\"asc\"},{\"name\":\"iSortingCols\",\"value\":1}]"
```

My final code looks like this:

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static string jQueryDataTable(string jsonAOData)
    {
        // Deserialize json into object             
        List<NameValue> jsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<NameValue>>(jsonAOData);
        CustomParams paramObject = new CustomParams();
        paramObject.sEcho = jsonData.Single(o=> o.Name == "sEcho").Value;
        paramObject.iColumns = jsonData.Single(o=>o.Name == "iColumns").Value;
        // the rest of the parameters

        // ... code ...
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting some error? What's not working! The only problem that I saw above was that the object that you wan to serialize is a property inside the JSON string. If you pass only the jsonAOData, will work.

Comment: Updated original post.

Comment: The error should be cause for what i said before. Just pass JSON.stringify(aoData) as parameter.

Comment: Like this: data: JSON.stringify(aoData) ?

Comment: @Fals that does not work for me I have to give it a name so I can use that name in code behind to get data string. Also updated original post with more progress.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67156/discussion-between-mike-r-and-fals).

Comment: What does the JSON for `aoData` look like?

Comment: It sounds like what you want is `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomParams>` but it depends on what the structure of your JSON is.

Comment: @AaronLS updated my original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your JSON is an array, it deserializes to an array/list. You will either need to manually map to your CustomObject class, use reflection, or use something like AutoMapper that automate some of this reflections.  You could implement a custom JSON deserializer, but it will still require you use reflection to assign values to properties.  This is the simplest way to do it without reflection:

```
var customObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<NameValue>>(jsonAOData);

CustomParams paramObject = new CustomParams();
paramObject.sEcho = customObj.Single(o=>o.Name == 'sEcho').Value;
paramObject.iColumns = customObj.Single(o=>o.Name == 'iColumns ').Value;
// etc.
```

**Reformatting the JSON**

If you have control over the JSON format, it would be better if you formatted like so as a flat object instead of array:

```
{ "sEcho":"1","iColumns":8, "sColumns":5, ... }
```

and then this can be Deserialized directly to a CustomParams object:

```
CustomParams paramObject= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomParams>(jsonAOData);
```

You could convert the original JSON array on the fly into a flat object from javascript before submitting it by looping through every item in the array to populate a new flat object:

```
flatObject[arrayItem.name] = arrayItem.value;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is perfect. I ended up using Linq to populate parameters in CustomParams object.